# Como verificar que un usuario ya existe en la base de datos con php POO?

Tags: php, mysql

Hola vengo a pedir su ayuda por favor, quiero validar que un usuario ya existes en la DB, pero no se como hacerlo, tengo el siguiente código en php orientado a objetos, desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda.
Disculpen que adjunto imgs, stack no me dejaba poner código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en PHP tengo el siguiente codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Por favor pon el código como texto (copiar y pegar) en vez de imágenes. Es más útil y más sencillo. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar la pregunta en ese sentido. Además, dinos que ocurre, si da error, que error, si no muestra nada en pantalla, etc.